# Xpath current() in Yang

Tags: xml, xpath, libxml2, ietf-netmod-yang

I have a leaf defined in Yang as:

```
leaf test-must {
    type int32;
    description "Test must";
    must "current() > 0" {
        error-message "test-must value should be > 0";
    }
}
```

Looks like the underlying library, `libxml2`, I use does not recognize `current()` when this is evaluated and returns error:

> error: xmlXPathCompOpEval: function current not found
>
> error: Unregistered function

Are there any alternatives to `current()`? Or where do I find definition for `current()` and register it?

As an alternative I tried with `.` and `self::node()` following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41751872/usage-of-current-vs-in-yang-xpath-expressions).

But when this expression is evaluated with `libxml2` APIs, when test-must value is configured as 0, it returns proper error. However, when test-must value is > 0, it says "invalid expression", which should not return error since value > 1 (which is Success as per must statement).

> error: Invalid expression

Can someone provide some help on this?

Comment: The function current() is defined only for use in XSLT, not in free-standing XPath. The use of "." is allowed in free-standing XPath, but I don't know Yang, so I don't know how you set the initial context item for the expression.

Comment: Thanks, if we have to implement our own function to support current() and register the same with libxml2 Xpath library, are there any existing examples or open source available?

Comment: In your example, `current() > 0` and `. > 0` are semantically equivalent. The initial context node would be an instance of `test-must` leaf. I've not used libxml2, but it seems very strange that it would report what appears to be a syntax error depending on values supplied at runtime. Are you sure the only thing you changed between the two tests was the value of your leaf instance?

Comment: Also note, depending on your YANG version, `current()` may not be the only XPath function you'll have to implement.

Comment: @predi, I have posted a follow up question @ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56375878/xpath-current-for-yang. Could you check?