# XPath current() for Yang

Tags: c, xml, xpath, libxml2, ietf-netmod-yang

This is my follow up question for [Xpath current() in Yang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55888566/xpath-current-in-yang) After the earlier discussion, I implemented a customized function current() for libxml2 with implementation shown below. The function works fine as expected when it evaluates Xpath expressions like:

```
leaf test-string {
  type string;
  must "current() > 0";
}
```

But when more complex expressions are involved like Xpath expresion "interface[name=current()/supporting-interface]/type = 'optical'", it does not seem to be working fine. Anything I am missing in the current() implementation.
Given below is my implementation. Also is there a way to print the ultimate Xpath expression that gets constructed by xmlXPathEvalExpression() API?

```
/*
 * ext_current () -- Defines the Xpath extension current(),
 * defined by Yang RFC.
 *
 * From Yang RFC 7950:
 *
 * The current() function takes no input parameters and returns a node
 * set with the initial context node as its only member.
 */
static void
ext_current (xmlXPathParserContextPtr ctxt, int nargs)
{
    /*
     * This function takes 0 args.
     */
    if (nargs != 0) {
        return;
    }

    /* Push the current context node onto Xpath Stack */
    valuePush(ctxt, xmlXPathNewNodeSet(ctxt->context->node));
}

/*
 * register_yang_xpath_extensions () -- Registers extensions defined by Yang
 * RFC.
 */
static void
register_yang_xpath_extensions (xmlXPathContextPtr ctxt)
{
    int rc = 0;

    rc = xmlXPathRegisterFunc(ctxt, (const xmlChar *)"current",
                              ext_current);
    if (rc != 0)
        fprintf(stderr, "Error in registering current() func\n");
}
```

Comment: I don't know libxml2 in any detail, but I suspect the value you are looking for (the item that was the context item at the outermost level of the XPath expression) is not available via this API. There's no reason it should be, because it's not a defined part of the XPath dynamic context and nothing in XPath uses it. You're returning the context item, which you can get equally well using ".".

Comment: Thanks, As per Yang RFC 10.1.  Function for Node Sets

10.1.1.  current()

     node-set current()

   The current() function takes no input parameters and returns a node
   set with the initial context node as its only member.
I implemented using this as reference and referring: https://www.w3schools.com/xml/func_current.asp

Comment: But not sure why Yang RFC had to define a new extension called current() when both "." and current() are same.

Comment: "." and "current()" in XSLT are definitely NOT the same. (And if you need to know the precise semantics, then steer well clear of w3schools which aims at ease of understanding rather than precise accuracy).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.` and `current()` are not the same in YANG, though they may return the same result in [certain situations](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41758475/878469). The result of `.` changes with XPath path steps (the **current** context node, as you yourself refer to in your code), while `current()` always returns the same node no matter where it is used within the same XPath expression - the **initial** context node.

The initial context node for an XPath expression in YANG depends on where this expression is defined with respect to YANG schema. A combination of rules in [RFC7950, Section 6.4.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7950#section-6.4.1) and these are used to determine the initial context node:

- `when` statement:

> The XPath expression is conceptually evaluated in the following
> context, in addition to the definition in Section 6.4.1:

o  If the "when" statement is a child of an "augment" statement, then
**the context node** is the augment's target node in the data tree, if
the target node is a data node.  Otherwise, **the context node** is
the closest ancestor node to the target node that is also a data
node.  If no such node exists, **the context node** is the root node.
The accessible tree is tentatively altered during the processing
of the XPath expression by removing all instances (if any) of the
nodes added by the "augment" statement.

> 

o  If the "when" statement is a child of a "uses", "choice", or
"case" statement, then **the context node** is the closest ancestor
node to the node with the "when" statement that is also a data
node.  If no such node exists, **the context node** is the root node.
The accessible tree is tentatively altered during the processing
of the XPath expression by removing all instances (if any) of the
nodes added by the "uses", "choice", or "case" statement.

> 

o  If the "when" statement is a child of any other data definition
statement, the accessible tree is tentatively altered during the
processing of the XPath expression by replacing all instances of
the data node for which the "when" statement is defined with a
single dummy node with the same name, but with no value and no
children.  If no such instance exists, the dummy node is
tentatively created.  **The context node** is this dummy node.

> 

[RFC7950, Section 7.21.5](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7950#section-7.21.5)

- `must` statement:

> The XPath expression is conceptually evaluated in the following
> context, in addition to the definition in Section 6.4.1:

o  If the "must" statement is a substatement of a "notification"
statement, **the context node** is the node representing the
notification in the accessible tree.

> 

o  If the "must" statement is a substatement of an "input" statement,
**the context node** is the node representing the operation in the
accessible tree.

> 

o  If the "must" statement is a substatement of an "output"
statement, **the context node** is the node representing the operation
in the accessible tree.

> 

o  Otherwise, **the context node** is the node in the accessible tree for
which the "must" statement is defined.

> 

[RFC7950, Section 7.5.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7950#section-7.5.3)

- `path` statement:

> The "path" XPath expression is conceptually evaluated in the
> following context, in addition to the definition in Section 6.4.1:

o  If the "path" statement is defined within a typedef, **the context
node** is the leaf or leaf-list node in the data tree that
references the typedef.

> 

o  Otherwise, **the context node** is the node in the data tree for which
the "path" statement is defined.

> 

[RFC7950, Section 9.9.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7950#section-9.9.2)

All of these rules need to be implemented in order to support standard YANG XPath, `current()` function included.